# Neo4j: find network of nodes of type A connected to more than one of type 2

Tags: neo4j

My network consists of groups of nodes of type A that have multiple relations between them (of different types, but not important ftm). Some of those nodes also could have a relation with a node of type B.
Now I'm looking for the groups of nodes of type A that are connected with more than  one of type B.
Is that even possible with Neo4j?

Comment: "I'm looking for the groups of nodes of type A" Do you mean "Any node of type A that is connected with more than one type B node"? Or "A group of nodes of type A (meaning they will be interconnected) that are also connected (as a group) to more than one type B node"?

Comment: I'm looking for the nodes of type A that are as a group connected to more than one type B nodes

Comment: So I take it there exist some nodes of type :A that are connected (via X amount of hops? Single hop?) to other :A nodes, but not other :A nodes?

Comment: And what you would like each row in the return value to contain? A list of :A nodes?

Comment: Indeed, that is what we had in mind

Answer (score 0):

### Example model

For the ease of possible further answers and solutions I note my graph creating statement:

```
CREATE
  (a1:TypeA {name: 'A1'})-[:REFERS]->(a2:TypeA {name: 'A2'}),
  (a1)-[:REFERS]->(a3:TypeA {name: 'A3'}),
  (a2)-[:REFERS]->(a4:TypeA {name: 'A4'}),
  (a3)-[:REFERS]->(a4),
  (c1:TypeC {name: 'C1'})-[:REFERS]->(a1),
  (c1)-[:REFERS]->(a2),
  (d1:TypeD {name: 'D1'})-[:REFERS]->(a1),
  (d1)-[:REFERS]->(a3),
  (b1:TypeB {name: 'B1'})-[:REFERS]->(a3),
  (b1)-[:REFERS]->(a4),
  (b2:TypeB {name: 'B2'})-[:REFERS]->(a4),
  (e1:TypeE {name: 'E1'})-[:REFERS]->(a3),
  (e1)-[:REFERS]->(b1);
```

[image: graphical representation of the example graph]

### Solution

The second line detects your `TypeA` network. Based on this the third line identifies all connected `TypeB`s, which are counted in line 5 and filtered in line 6.

```
MATCH
  networkA = (startNode:TypeA)-[:REFERS]-(:TypeA)-[:REFERS]-(:TypeA)-[:REFERS]-(:TypeA)-[:REFERS]-(:TypeA),
  (startNode)-[:REFERS]-(nodeB:TypeB)
WITH
  nodes( networkA) AS networkANodes, count(nodeB) AS nodeBAmount
WITH networkANodes WHERE nodeBAmount >= 2
RETURN
  networkANodes;
```

### Result

```
╒══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╕
│"networkANodes"                                                       │
╞══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│[{"name":"A4"},{"name":"A3"},{"name":"A1"},{"name":"A2"},{"name":"A4"}│
│]                                                                     │
├──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│[{"name":"A4"},{"name":"A2"},{"name":"A1"},{"name":"A3"},{"name":"A4"}│
│]                                                                     │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

[image: graphical representation of the result]